# What does breakat&vim mean?

Tags: formatting, whitespace, line-breaks

I'm trying to understand this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19624717/1698426). The snippet reads:

```
:set nolist wrap linebreak breakat&vim
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It resets the `breakat` option to the Vim default: `^I!@*-+;:,./?`.

Where `^I` stands for the tab character.

You get the corresponding help paragraph with the `:help :set-default` command.

```
:se[t] {option}&    Reset option to its default value.  May depend on the
                    current value of 'compatible'.
:se[t] {option}&vi  Reset option to its Vi default value.
:se[t] {option}&vim Reset option to its Vim default value.
```